# HEVC Intra Prediction Reference Sample Handling

Tags: matlab, video, video-processing, hevc, avvideocomposition

I have been working on a project in implementing HEVC Intra prediction for my bachelor thesis and first step of the project is to implement the algorithm on Matlab. I found limited number of papers about the subject and I am having a hard time constructing the reference samples for angular prediction. I found the below information in one of the papers:

1. all sample locations within one prediction block are projected to a single
   reference row or column, using the left reference column for angular modes 2 to 17 and the above reference row for angular modes 18 to 34
2. In some cases, the projected pixel locations would have negative indexes. In these cases, the reference row or column is extended by projecting the left reference column to extend the top reference row toward left, or projecting the top reference row to extend the left reference column upward

Can anyone please provide more insight about this? For example,in order to project the samples to a single reference row, for modes 2 to 17, should I directly copy the left reference column? In addition, in the case of projected pixel locations have negative indexes, how can I correctly extend the reference row or column? Also, it would be great if you can provide the name of papers that have helped you about understanding the subject.

Comment: If you are familiar with C++, you could have a look at the reference software HM. (You can get it here: https://hevc.hhi.fraunhofer.de/) You would have to search a bit. What I can tell you is that the intra prediction happens in the `estIntraPredLumaQT` function in TEncSearch.cpp

Comment: Have you found the answers to your questions? I'm wondering if you could share your solution.